# Minimum string with certain properities

Tags: algorithm

Let's say i have a string of N positive integers containing K different integers.For example this string:1 3 1 3 1 3 3 2 2 1.For this string N=10,K=3(1,2,3).What i want is to find the smallest substring that contains all K integers.In this case the solution would be 1 3 3 2 or 3 2 2 1.

I thought about checking this string from left to right and creating a new string.In this new string i would name the first integer as "first" and compare it's value with every integer i am checking at the time.If the integer i am about to add is the same with the first element i erase the first element from the string and the first+1 element becomes the new `first.After that i also need to check the elements following the first(previous first)and check if first+1 and first+2..first+n are the same(f.e. 3 3 3) i erase all of them except from the nth element.I could also keep track of the different elements that belong in the list i am building and when it reaches K hold this value and update it only if a find a smaller subset.However,i think this is not the optimal solution to this and i believe this could somehow be done in linear time.Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in linear for sure.

Initially, let's find the shortest prefix which hits all `K` values, then we would drop first item and enlarge new prefix until it hits and so on. Answer is simply minimal length of those prefixes.

```
cnt[K] = {0, 0, ..., 0} # cnt[i] == how many times we hit value i
nonzero_cnt = 0 # how many different values we hit

hi = 0 # right border
ans = N+1 # len of shortest subsegment found so far, >N on init to be relaxated
for lo = [0, N):  # left border (or how many first elements we droped)
    while nonzero_cnt < N: # moving right border until subsegment is good
        if hi = N: STOP() # right border did all the way to boundary
        if cnt[hi] = 0:
            nonzero_cnt += 1
        cnt[hi] += 1
        hi += 1
    ans = min(ans, hi-lo)
    cnt[lo] -= 1 # left border moved to right by one
    if cnt[lo] = 0:
        nonzero_cnt -= 1
```